# shipping calculator for expresso store

Tags: expresso-store

Not sure if a new question is the right thing?  There was a question a month ago about users being able to calculate shipping on the first page of checkout.

In the template I substituted:

```
{field:shipping_method}
{if error:shipping_method}<p class="help-block">{error:shipping_method}</p>{/if}
```

for

```
<label>Shipping State</label>
{field:shipping_region}
<input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Shipping" class="btn" />
```

The aim was to update `{order_shipping}` on the same page.  This doesn't work.

I would appreciate some help on this.  Cheers,  Alex

Comment: I don't understand the question. Which shipping methods are you using? What happens when you click the "update shipping" button you added? Can you link to the previous question you are referring to?

Comment: Using the default shipping module. Have a very simple setup as all deliveries are in NZ and fall into 4 categories - SI, SI Rural,  NI, NI Rural. I only have one product.  Have a shipping method (Shipping) setup and four rules which base shipping rates on the Region.   This works fine on Checkout2 and 3 but I want the purchaser to be able to select the region and see the cost of shipping at the checkout 1 stage.   I am getting the dropdown list rendering but when I select a region the {order_shipping} does not update and the selection does not "stick".  Not sure how to link to old question?

Comment: The default shipping plugin needs at least a country to calculate the shipping, having said that you would need to make sure that the user has entered the city and postal code to get the accurate shipping cost. On your first page have you had the user enter their shipping details?

Comment: Thanks Justin.  I only ship in NZ.   I have four regions as above.  I just want the purchaser to be able to select their region from a drop down and see the delivery price on the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Justin's excellent support pointed out my error.

In the ExpressionEngine control panel Store >> Settings >> General >> Default Shipping Address can be set to "None", "Shipping Same as Billing" or  "Billing Same as Shipping"

If you have it set to "Shipping the same as billing" you would need to make sure that you have {field:billing_region} instead of {field:shipping_region} or visa-verse if you have "Billing same as Shipping".

I had it set to "Shipping same as Billing" and changing {field:shipping_region} to {field:billing_region} sorted the issue.